# IIS Sub-application root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, subapplication

I have an existing Web Application hosted in IIS which an ASP.NET MVC application. Now I want to add a sub application,But when I deploy, some relative paths like "~/" or "/" will be imported back to my parent application.

Example:
The URL of the parent application is https://www.example.com/

Then my sub application is https://www.example.com/subApp/

When I try to click on the "subApp/test" page, it should be directed to https://www.example.com/subApp/test, but he still leads back to https://www.example.com/test.

How can I solve it?
Can it be modified through Web.Config instead of going to each page one by one

Comment: Where did you click on the "subApp/test" page? Can you successfully access https://www.example.com/subApp/test?

Answer (score 0):

check your URL rewriting module. if it is there?

Comment: Can I not use rewriting ?

Comment: Yes you can use. But your iis needs a url rewriting module.. download it from Microsoft site according to the your iis version